# Django: Use htaccess to protect django app

Tags: python, django, apache, .htaccess

I have a staging server with identical source code to the production server.
I want to keep the public outside of the staging server so I thought of using htaccess to limit users to the staging server (and keep robots and strangers outside).

Somehow its not working for me.

I created the passwordfile

```
sudo htpasswd -cs /var/.passwd staging
```

I placed the .htaccess file in

```
/var/www/djangoapp/
```

.htaccess:

```
AuthUserFile /var/.passwd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Just testing"
Require valid-user
```

I ensured:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Apache restart:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

The Django Application is still available for everybody. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your password file needs to be named .htpasswd

Comment: This looks strange to me. Why would the django app files be open to the free world in any case? Place them outside apache root and properly configure the vhost.

Comment: I renamed it to .htpasswd. The issue remains

Comment: Not the source code is publicly available, the Website powered by the django app is. On staging it has test data, and is for internal use only.

Comment: You can name the password file however you like. I just used your configuration in my test environment and it works as expected. There must be something else allowing anyone access. Maybe the pages are cached somewhere. Try using curl or wget and see, if you can still access the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative solution to the above goal without htaccess.
I would like to share:

in 000-default-conf in the respective virtualhost section:

```
<Directory /var/www/djangoapp/djangoapp>
        AuthUserFile /var/.htpasswd
        AuthName "Just testing"
        AuthType Basic
        Require valid-user

        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require valid-user
        </Files>
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</Directory>
```

Of course this solution works only if you have access to this config file on your server. Anyway it solved my issue.
I could not figure out why the original setup in my question is not working for me.